gcloud functions deploy command always creates new function
I'm trying to update the memory of an existing cloud functions through the cli but instead of updating it creates a new function.
I've tried several commands from the docs but it still creates everytime.
gcloud functions deploy {func_name} --memory=512MB --gen2
gcloud functions deploy {func_name} --trigger-http --memory=512MB --gen2 --project={proj_name} --source=.
gcloud functions deploy {func_name} --memory=512MB --runtime nodejs18 --region {region_name} --gen2 --trigger-http
What is the proper syntax to update an existing cloud functions? I just want to update the memory.
UPDATE: I was able to update the memory by directly changing the value in the cloud functions config through the console. I encountered a couple more issues when trying to do it through cli.

Is "the cli" the Firebase cli?

@RenaudTarnec gcloud cli

There is no such feature in gcloud.  You can see the list of gcloud functions commands for yourself in the documentation, and you will find no way to update a function.  If you want to change a function, you will need to redeploy it with new options as you are doing now.

Do you mean it's replacing the function? If yes, this is the expected behavior, even if you just intend to update the memory.
However, if the command is creating a brand new function, then there must be something wrong.
Since you're deploying a gen2 function, you can see all revisions that Cloud Run creates behind the scenes. Just go to Cloud Run -> {func_name} -> Revisions tab.
This shows that new deployments are not technically "new functions". They are just new revisions under the same service.
